# How to enable debug logging in Eucalyptus 4.0.0?

Tags: debugging, eucalyptus

Can anyone explain how to enable debug logging in Eucalyptus 4.0.0 properly?
I set `LOGLEVEL="DEBUG"` in `/etc/eucalyptus/eucalyptus.conf`

Then I restarted everything but logs still only show `INFO`, `WARN` and `ERROR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. Setting LOGLEVEL="DEBUG" in eucalyptus.conf is valid for C-based components, and Java-based components which have not yet fully bootstrapped. When you set DEBUG in eucalyptus.conf, you'll need to restart the affected components on just that machine. So for example, on the NC, you would need to issue a restart, eg, "service eucalyptus-nc restart" in order to pick up the new value.

For the Java components, in particular after they've bootstrapped, you set the cloud-wide PROPERTY thusly:

```
euca-modify-property -p cloud.euca_log_level=DEBUG
```

and the output will tell you what the property was, and what is has become, if done correctly.

For example:

```
# euca-modify-property -p cloud.euca_log_level=DEBUG
PROPERTY        cloud.euca_log_level    DEBUG was INFO
```

Once you've set that, you're good to go. No need to restart any of the Java components, anywhere in the cloud.